# Is there a way to encourage specific types of questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently I answered the following three questions:

[How does Rambam explain why we don't ask for rain until the end of sukkos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86136/how-does-rambam-explain-why-we-dont-ask-for-rain-until-the-end-of-sukkos)

[Understanding תוד״ה תפילין on קידושין דף לו ע״א](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98824/understanding-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-on-%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%93%D7%A3-%D7%9C%D7%95-%D7%A2-%D7%90)

[Why would I have thought that healing contradicts the will of Hashem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98956/why-would-i-have-thought-that-healing-contradicts-the-will-of-hashem)

I realized that these are all a particular type of question. I don't know if there's any precise term to categorize them, but I would say something like "they are the type of question that comes up when learning a sugiah" as opposed to just a specific question about a particular Jewish law or Jewish custom or Jewish belief. The questions are more about "figuring out a peshat" than getting a simple answer.

I quite enjoyed those questions, and I realized that I don't often see these types of questions on Mi Yodeya.

Two comments in Chat reinforced the idea that such types of questions might not be so popular here:

[Isaac Moses said:](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48744814#48744814)

> Unfortunately, I suspect that we don't have nearly as broad a base of readers/voters/editors for lomdus Q&A as we do for other major realms of Torah, such as applied Halacha and Parshanut.

[Monica Cellio said:](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48744716#48744716)

> [T]he question currently has 44 views -- looks like the title and opening few words of the question aren't drawing people in, so they don't get as far as the answer. Just speculating, but perhaps you can think of an edit that might improve that?

Personally, I would like to see more of this type of question. Is there any way to potentially encourage people to ask more of these types of questions?

I realize that some of the pitfalls of such questions are that they are inherently more "chatty" or "forummy", and often don't have a definitive answer. However, many questions on Mi Yodeya don't have a definitive answer, and [it seems that these types of questions are still considered on-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/would-this-be-an-appropriate-site-for-people-to-ask-technical-gemara-questions).

Any suggestions?

(Suggestions can include suggesting that it would be a bad idea to try to encourage these types of questions, or that my premise is incorrect and we already have a lot of these types of questions.)

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're interested in these types of questions. I used to ask them here, but they mostly got little attention. If you're interested in a couple more, feel free to take a crack at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56710/1713 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60985/1713 :)

Comment: Generally speaking if you want questions, you have to have a [user base that would ask them](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/295/759). "Is there any way to potentially encourage people to ask more of these types of questions?" is probably backwards. You may want to find out how to encourage retention of users who have those kinds of questions. Once they're here they'll take care of the asking.

Comment: Im my  opinion a contributing factor may be the fact that normal discussion of Gemara (or tosafos etc.) is not done using the terminology normally required for a competent answer on MY. Which therefore discourages such questions.

Comment: This it is a good idea, because, unlike other type of answers, these don’t  necessarily require extensive sources and the like, rather just another pair of hands