# What is a model type of question for Mi Yodeya? And the opposite

Tags: discussion

I am trying to get to the bottom of what Mi Yodeya is all about. It's hard. Is it a place to ask halacha? Find out about tradition? Get answers to assist with homework questions? Run ideas by each other? Jewish history? Get help with sources?

---

The highest scoring question of all time: [Implications of Samoa skipping a Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday)

The highest scoring question (by far) since the stack exchange moderator fiasco: [Why does my bottle of Kosher grape juice say that it's 'for sacramental purposes only'?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94572/why-does-my-bottle-of-kosher-grape-juice-say-that-its-for-sacramental-purposes)

[Halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha) and [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-mekorot) are the most popular tags

---

The least scoring question that's not closed or untznius: [Where did Moses' applied scientific knowledge disappear?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105160/where-did-moses-applied-scientific-knowledge-disappear)

Here is the lowest scoring answer with over 10,000 views (that isn't closed, offensive or downvoted because it was an obviously wrong question): [What are the exact Shmita dates (in Gregorian) since 1900 or a general formula for determining the dates?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45768/what-are-the-exact-shmita-dates-in-gregorian-since-1900-or-a-general-formula-f)

---

So what sort of question would people like to see more of, and what sort of questions would people prefer to see less of? Especially lately.

Comment: Note that score, especially extreme high score, is not a perfect proxy for value to the community. The highest-scoring questions tend to be ones that get featured on the network-wide "Hot Network Questions" sidebar and that are sufficiently interesting to a wide cross-section of the Stack Exchange world (mostly programmers) to get many click-throughs. "Samoa" is an example of this.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to encourage specific types of questions?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4892/is-there-a-way-to-encourage-specific-types-of-questions)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the ideal question:

- Follows all of the general guidance for ideal Stack Exchange questions found in [How do I ask a good question?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- Is [about Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- Is written from the [point of view of](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/2) genuine curiosity on the part of the asker
- Expresses the [motivation](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2162/2) for the asker's curiosity, including relevant sources the asker is already aware of
- Is written in well-formed, well-organized English, with a [minimum of jargon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon), such that it is pleasing and clear to read for any English-speaker who is interested in the topic

  - Therefore, is as long as it needs to be to clearly express the question, [and no longer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/is-it-a-virtue-to-keep-questions-answers-succinct)

If a question post includes all of these qualities, I would be very likely to consider it ideal, regardless of what topic within Judaism it's about. I may be personally more or less interested in the question depending on the topic, and may choose to allocate my attention accordingly, as may any other reader.

However, I would strongly encourage you to mostly ignore others' interest in a topic as a primary consideration, and focus on asking what *you* are interested in. Niche topics may get less attention and, for what it's worth (not much), fewer votes, but if they're well-written, they'll stick around, and Google searching will eventually bring them the niche love they deserve.